# Sending request from URL address and got error

Tags: api, url, bitrix

> https:?fields[OWNER_TYPE_ID]=4&fields[OWNER_ID]=23920&fields[TYPE_ID]=2&fields[COMMUNICATIONS][VALUE]="998974602446"&fields[SUBJECT]="new%20phone"&fields[START_TIME]=2022-09-17%2015:00:00&fields[END_TIME]=2022-09-17%2015:30:00&fields[COMPLETED]="N"&fields[PRIORITY]=3&fields[RESPONSIBLE_ID]=646&fields[DESCRIPTION]="важный%20звонок"&fields[DESCRIPTION_TYPE]=0

I am sending this request from URL and got some error {"error":"","error_description":"The field COMMUNICATIONS is not defined or invalid."}
I am doing something wrong and I don't know from this documentation I am doing what they are saying. Can someone help me solve this problem?
&fields[COMMUNICATIONS][VALUE]="998974602446" what I miss here

https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/rest_help/crm/rest_activity/crm_activity_add.php

Answer (score 0):

If the above method is not working possible there can two errors,
One is improper quotation or could be that the routes is not being handedover.

If the above two are good to go but still having the same error you can use some lightweight package for logging (ex- [Winston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64414147/set-winston-to-log-the-url-path-on-express) or `Morgan` for JS).

Comment: in documentation they are saying we need to write like this fields{"COMMUNICATION": [  { VALUE:"+79832322323"}], }if I ran python code its working well but I cannot understand why from URL I can't add this  &fields[COMMUNICATIONS][VALUE]="998974602446" this part something I miss I guest

Comment: Is COMMUNICATION defined anywhere else??

Comment: It solvel we need to add between &[COMMUNICATION][0][VALUE] and the request will work